# MFC : creating a hyperlink in a button

Tags: mfc, button, visual-c++, hyperlink

Is there an easy way in MFC to add a hyperlink in a button? I've searched the net and they seem to offer complicated stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/dd450359.aspx) shows how to use the [SysLink common control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760704%28VS.85%29.aspx) ([CLinkCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdfd1sb4%28VS.71%29.aspx)). Beware that MFC support for this control is new and requires VS2008 and the Feature Pack.

Bear in mind that the SysLink control is XP+. If you have to support older platforms, or if you use an older VS, your best bet is probably the good old [CStaticLink](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1297/c1297.aspx) by [Paul DiLascia](http://www.dilascia.com/) (RIP).

Comment: Wow! I didn't know such a thing exists. Is there any way we could remove the underline in the link?

Comment: I don't think so but I don't have in depth knowledge of this control. I would be surprised since the purpose is to mimic basic HTML links so that users understand they can click the text.

Answer (score 0):

MFC doesn't implement buttons with hyperlinks (actually win32 *common* buttons don't support it).

You'll have to use 3rd party buttons.
One option is to use the [FooButton](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/FooButton.aspx) class which supports hyperlinks.